# Override SSDT publish profile ConnectionString

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage

I am using the following command to generate to publish database changes using SSDT:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /sf:DB.dacpac /Profile:publish.xml
```

I would like to supply database connection string as an argument instead of using a hard coded connection string from publish.xml. Is there anyway I can override it?

I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /sf:DB.dacpac /Profile:publish.xml /TargetConnectionString:$ConnectionString
```

where $ConnectionString is an argument from Jenkins. However, it still uses ConnectionString from publish.xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source code with reflector (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.ValidationUtil) and what happens is that TargetConnectionString is read from the command line, then after that the value in the publish profile overwrites the value - that can't be changed I am afraid.

The interesting thing is that after it has the connection string from either /TargetConnectionString or the publish profile it then applies the individual properties such as /TargetDatabaseName so *i think* (untested but looks good from the code) if instead of passing /TargetConnectionString you pass the individual components such as:

/TargetUser, /TargetPassword, /TargetDatabaseName, /TargetServerName, etc.

Then I think it will override the connection string in the publish profile, it is quite hard to read so let me know how you get on!

ed

Comment: Interesting, thanks for checking. I will give a try and get back to you.

Comment: Great :) it might be worth raising a connect bug asking for it to be the other way around *or* updating the documentation:)